# React Native event trigger when app quit state

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, alarm

I want to trigger alarm in app when fcm push notification received, when app is closed (quit state) but there is no event trigger.

I'm using

- @react-native-firebase/app
- @react-native-firebase/messaging

Is there any way to trigger an event when app is in quit state.

I'm using this package for alarm

- react-native-alarm-notification

All is working fine in foreground and in background.

Comment: I am facing similar issues, nothing is shown actually on screen. Did you find a solution? Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the index.js in the root directory:

```js
const backgroundHandler= async (message)=>{
If(message){
    console.log(this is the firebase quit state message,
    message)}
    return
}
appregistry.registerheadlesstask(
        'ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask',
         (message)=>backgroundHandler )
```

This happens when there is no notification object in the object that is recieved from fcm.
This is a way to fix this issue if this was you problem